# Sharing Ubuntu disk to Windows over the network

Tags: windows, permissions

I have got a HP Prolient mini sever in which I have added 2 additional 2TB Drives setup as a RAID 1 to give redundancy with the view to using it as a central repository for storing photos etc. I could not get Ubuntu Server to install so gave up and installed 12.04 Desktop version

I installed Ubuntu on the 250 GB drive leving the other empty. all installed fine. I then used Disk Utility to setup the 2TB drives as DATA, this says mount point `/media/DATA`

This drive appears in the shortcuts and I can read and write to it. So far all fine, the problem I have is I cannot access it from my windows laptop. I have shared the folder but makes no difference. I can see the folder in windows but cannot open it.

I think the problem is permissions, but I don't know how to change them as I cannot find the drive through shell.

How can I share `/media/DATA` in a way I can access it from my Windows laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You can install samba to share this driver :

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` you can state permissions on this share and allow specific users to use this share .

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share (here the name)
    path = /srv/samba/share (here the path of your share)
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

You can also give permission to your share by :

```
sudo chmod 755 /share path (drwxr-xr-x)
```

Comment: Do you use this setup yourself? What are the down sides?